# how to capture DB Screen shot with Code version?

Tags: svn, design-patterns, version-control, theory

My Product is in development phase : We are releasing to QC with Versions and cut a branch and update to SVN, how to keep the DB schema screenshot. Currently we keep DB screenshot manually and tag it with version. Is there a Better way, so that at any point of time we have Code n DB for any version.
Kindly suggest.